# Rotating logs generated from tcpdump with logrotate

Tags: kill, logrotate, tcpdump

On one production linux box, I am capturing SIP packets using the following configuration:

**logrotate.conf:**

```
# Opensips SIP traces 
/var/log/sip.log
{
        rotate 31
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                pkill tcpdump
                /home/ubuntu/log-sip-messages.sh &
        endscript
}
```

**log-sip-messages.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
tcpdump host 159.63.X.X -s0 -v >> /var/log/sip-159.63.X.X.log
```

This works great on the Ubuntu 11.04 server, but on the Ubuntu 12.10 boxes, this just produces a file with a timestamp at the time the logs were rotated. It's as if the pkill doesn't complete before running tcpdump again to start writing to the new file.

I've tried running this directly from the terminal as an experiment:

```
pkill tcpdump && tcpdump -s0 -v udp >> /var/log/sip.log
```

and then when I run `ps aux|grep tcpdump` there's no process running, confirming what I already know... the pkill command runs asynchronously on 12.10 (but either is synchronous on 11.04 or just beats the 2nd command)

How can I make this work so I can capture network traffic in a nice, readable log file (I don't need pcaps) without risking filling up my hard drive space?

Comment: As an aside, do we need a pkill tag or is kill enough to convey the message?

Comment: We haven't felt the need for a pkill tag in three years, and this question isn't related to pkill specifically but to signals in general, so I don't see the point of adding a pkill tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this inspired me to dig into the logrotate manpage to see what sort of tools are at my disposal. I discovered that `copytruncate` makes a copy of the log file and then truncates it, but without disrupting the process that writes to it. My testing shows that it does rotate the logs and allow tcpdump to continue writing to the cleared file. I left an hourly cronjob running overnight using a test configuration file so I would rotate these logs every hour. It worked:

```
# Opensips SIP traces 
/var/log/sip.log
{
        rotate 31
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        copytruncate
}
```

One possible downside is that, if the tcpdump process is killed by someone who doesn't know what I'm doing, I'd have to come in and manually restart the process, but this is sufficient for now.

The other potential issue is that, if the log file is very large, making a copy may briefly require a lot of disk space, for which I have plenty at the moment, but the process may be interrupted if there isn't enough room to make a copy.

Answer (score 5):

Unix signal delivery is asynchronous. When the `kill` system call returns, the signal has been delivered to the process, but the process may not have reacted to it yet. You were lucky with the scheduler under 11.04. If the killed process has a handler for the signal, it can spend an arbitrarily long time before dying, or choose not to die as a result of the signal.

You could use a lock to ensure that the new instance of the process doesn't start until the previous one has finished.

Furthermore, I don't recommend indiscriminately killing `tcpdump` processes: what if there are other instances running? Instead, kill any process that has the lock file open.

```
#!/bin/sh
lockfile=/var/run/log-sip-messages.lock
# Kill all processes that have the lock file open
fuser -k -TERM "$lockfile" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
(
  # Wait until the lock is released
  flock -s 3
  # Don't let this shell be killed by fuser: wait until tcpdump exits
  trap : TERM
  # Call tcpdump with the lock file open, so that fuser kills it
  tcpdump -s0 -v udp >> /var/log/sip.log
) 3>"$lockfile"
```

And from logrotate, run `/home/ubuntu/log-sip-messages.sh` only.

Comment: do you mind if I expand how this works?

Comment: Yeh, killing tcpdump was sort of messy and inelegant. It's a start, but I definitely like the lock file idea. @slm, I personally wouldn't mind expansion on how it works.

Comment: @jmort253 I've added comments, are they enough? And I also fixed a race condition.

Comment: @Gilles - yeah that's much clearer now, I know it makes it look busier now, but it's easier to understand.

Comment: If you want to read more about how to use `trap` check out this guide: http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to introduce some wait time between the `pkill` and the starting back up of the `tcpdump` (`/home/ubuntu/log-sip-messages.sh &`). This feels like a hack, and it is, but something like this:

```
    postrotate
            pkill tcpdump
            sleep 3
            /home/ubuntu/log-sip-messages.sh &
    endscript
```